# injecting property values into a map

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following set up, but i cannot get the values to be injected into my configuration class to create a map

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppConfig.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

my config class, where the map is always null

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppConfig {

    private Map<String, MyObject> objectMap;

    public Map<String, MyObject> getObjectMap() {
        return objectMap;
    }

    public void setObjectMap(Map<String, MyObject> objectMap) {
        this.objectMap = objectMap;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class MyObject {
    private String property1;
    private int property2;
}
```

my application properties

```
myapp.objectMap.key1.property1=value1
myapp.objectMap.key1.property2=42
myapp.objectMap.key2.property1=value2
myapp.objectMap.key2.property2=24
```

my gradle is as follows

```kotlin
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
```

Anyone know how i can get the properties into my class

Comment: It seems that lombok annotations stop the fields from being populated. If i generate my own setters the objects get populated? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try it in the following way

Define SpringBootApplication class in following way-

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MySpringApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final MyAppProperties myAppProperties;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("myEmployeeConfig: {}", myAppProperties);
    }
}
```

Now define ConfigurationProperties class as given below -

```java
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppProperties {
    private Map<String, ObjectMap> objectMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Data
    public static class ObjectMap {
        private String property1;
        private int property2;
    }
}
```

Finally your application.properties will look like following -

```
myapp.objectMap.key1.property1=value1
myapp.objectMap.key1.property2=42
myapp.objectMap.key2.property1=value2
myapp.objectMap.key2.property2=24
```

Answer (score 0):

With below code snippets, able to fetch data from application properties file into bean class.

**Changes:**

1. Created `MyObject` class as nested static class within `MyAppConfig`
2. Created a constructor in `MyAppConfig` after introducing class level
   annotation `ConstructorBinding`

**Main Class:**

```
package org.learn.springboot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppConfig.class)
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    MyAppConfig appConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println(appConfig.getObjectMap().size());
    }
}
```

MyAppConfig class:

```
package org.learn.springboot;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;

import java.util.Map;

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppConfig {

    private Map<String, MyObject> objectMap;

    public MyAppConfig(Map<String, MyObject> objectMap) {
        this.objectMap = objectMap;
    }

    public Map<String, MyObject> getObjectMap() {
        return objectMap;
    }

    public void setObjectMap(Map<String, MyObject> objectMap) {
        this.objectMap = objectMap;
    }


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    public static class MyObject {
        private String property1;
        private int property2;
    }
}
```

application.properties file:

```
myapp.objectMap.key1.property1=value1
myapp.objectMap.key1.property2=42
myapp.objectMap.key2.property1=value2
myapp.objectMap.key2.property2=24
```

Maven pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.learn.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootAppProps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```